# Xcode -GitHub Authentication Failed

Tags: ios, xcode, github

I'm trying to access GitHub through Xcode Preferences > Accounts > GitHub but every time I enter my email address and Personal Access Token it fails.

I entered (both manually and c+p) the token from my GitHub in yellow

Xcode:

[image]

GitHub Personal access token section:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at your screenshot, it looks like you're uploading the access token name, not the actual access token key. I've provided an example below:

[image]

When you first create the token you'll have an option to see the key. The value that appears next to the permissions (what you have in yellow) is just the name of it.

Comment: I think you're right. I did this so long ago that I forgot about it. Where can I find the key at?

Comment: Glad to hear this helped! You need to create a new token - you can only view the key  immediately after creation. For full directions: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: I actually found my token. I had it written down on a piece of paper. I'm going to upvote the answer too. THANK YOU!!!